# Jest spyOn mockReturnValue is returning undefined values

Tags: jestjs

I've got an odd error where while using Jest `spyOn` and mocking a returned value, that object's value get returned as undefined.

```
import { Location as LocationAPI } from '../index'
import REST from '../../MafRestApi'
const mockCoordinatesArray = [{'longitude': 116.0654299154163, 'latitude': -33.85910894972095, 'altitude': 1182.5}]

it('Calls the Location Coordinates API and gets a response', () => {
    jest.spyOn(REST, 'get').mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(mockCoordinatesArray))
    return LocationAPI.getLocationCoordinates()
        .then((results) => {
            expect(results).toEqual(mockCoordinatesArray)
        })
})
```

The `LocationAPI.getLocationCoordinates()` methods looks like this:

```
getLocationCoordinates (): Promise<Array<LocationCoordinates>> {
    return REST.get(`${ENDPOINTS.LOCATION}`)
        .then((coordinates) => coordinates.map((coordinate) => new LocationCoordinates(coordinate)))
}
```

This the `spyOn` is successfully intercepting.

The output from Jest results in:

```
Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected)

Expected value to equal: [{"altitude": 1182.5, "latitude": -33.85910894972095, "longitude": 116.0654299154163}]
Received:[{"altitude": undefined, "latitude": undefined, "longitude": undefined}]
```

I've used exactly the same signature for another API call and it's working fine.

Why would the keys be kept intact where the values not?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with the minimal code that reproduces the error? As far as I can see you are returning an array of `LocationCoordinates` from your `getLocationCoordinates` but in the test you are comparing it to an array.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem in your `getLocationCoordinates`. `getLocationCoordinates` is not returning the mapped `coordinates` in your code.

Try this:

```js
getLocationCoordinates(): Promise<Array<LocationCoordinates>> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    REST.get(`${ENDPOINTS.LOCATION}`).then((coordinates) => {
      const mappedCoordinates = coordinates.map((coordinate) => new LocationCoordinates(coordinate))
      resolve(mappedCoordinates);
    });
  });
}
```

or using `async/await`:

```js
async getLocationCoordinates(): Promise<Array<LocationCoordinates>> {
  const coordinates = await REST.get(`${ENDPOINTS.LOCATION}`);
  return coordinates.map((coordinate) => new LocationCoordinates(coordinate));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm pretty sure that's what the `jest.spyOn(REST, 'get').mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(mockCoordinatesArray))` is doing for me. I'm mocking out the REST.get call, with a resolved promised.